# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to list all of my databases,so i've used this code:

```
$db_list=mysql_list_dbs($con);
while($db=mysql_fetch_object($db_list))
echo $db;
```

But i get this error "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" , any idea??

Comment: because you are trying to print an object, use var_dump($db);

Comment: On a matter that do not have anything to do with the actual question (but is never the less important!), id like to add: do not use the deprecated `mysql` API. Take a look at `mysqli` or `PDO` for up-to-date APIs with similar functionality.

Comment: @Jite i know,but i have to use mysql at moment, jetawe i dont really want to echo it,but i need to be sure that the databases are listed,so i can use the $db_list later.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i've changed the mysqli into mysql...so this is not the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youre trying to echo an object. Should be:

```
$db_list = mysql_list_dbs($con);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($db_list)) {
     echo $row->Database . '<br/>'; // target the property
}
```

> **Warning:** This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.4.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

Use `mysqli_*` instead.

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');
$query = $db->query('SHOW DATABASES');
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['Database'] . '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP can't echo an object that isn't a String (i.e. your $db object). If you use `var_dump($db)`
you should be able to see the contents of $db

Comment: it shows just the boolean value which is false...i dont really want to echo it,but i need to be sure that he listed the databases so i can use the $db_list later

Answer (score 1):

you can use `var_dumb` or `print_r()`

For eg:

```
var_dump($db)

print_r($db)
```

Because echo just print a statement only. you need to print object or arrays use `var_dumb` or `print_r()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo $db->Database;
```

**<kbd>[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-dbs.php)</kbd>**